# What is the difference between npm run-script and npm run?

Tags: npm

I've seen references to both `npm run <task>` and `npm run-script <task>`.  What's the difference?

There are lots of posts on here about the difference between e.g. `npm build` and `npm run build`, but I've not found anything that compares `run` and `run-script`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm run` is an alias for `npm run-script`, so they're the same.

You can see this in the docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

You can also work this out by running `npm help run`.  The start of the output you'll get is:

```
NAME
       npm-run-script - Run arbitrary package scripts

   Synopsis
         npm run-script <command> [--silent] [-- <args>...]

         alias: npm run
```